# Robotic Path Planning - A* (Star)

Tags: c++, a-star

I'm implementing A* path planning algorithm for my main robots exploration behavior in C++. As the robot moves, it maps the environment around itself as a 2D graph. From this graph, I have set a Vector2D Tuple `{x, y}` which holds the location of this waypoint, where I want the robot to navigate too.

The first thing I do with A* is to have a `Node` class, which holds information about the current node;

```
double f; //  F, final score
double g; // Movement cost
double h; // Hueristic cost (Manhatten)
Node* parent;
Vector2d position;
```

As A* starts, I have my starting node as my Robots starting position (I also hold this position as a Vector for easy access). Then, I enter a while loop until the end goal is found. The first thing I do in this loop is to generate eight adjacent Nodes (Left, Bottom, Right, Top, Top-left, Top-Right, Bottom-Left, Bottom Right), I then return this in a `OpenList` vector.

// Open List is current nodes to check
    std::vector positions;

```
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX() - gridSize, current->position.getY())); // Left of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX() + gridSize, current->position.getY())); // right of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX(), current->position.getY() + gridSize)); // Top of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX(), current->position.getY() - gridSize)); // Bottom of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX() + gridSize,current->position.getY() + gridSize)); // Top Right of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX() - gridSize,current->position.getY() + gridSize)); // Top Left of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX() + gridSize,current->position.getY() - gridSize)); // Bottom Right of my current grid space (parent node)
positions.push_back(Vector2d(current->position.getX() - gridSize,current->position.getY() - gridSize)); // Bottom Left of my current grid space (parent node)

// moving diagnolly has a bigger cost
int movementCost[8] = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 14, 14, 14 };

// loop through all my positions and calculate their g, h and finally, f score.
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
{
    Node* node = new Node(positions[i]);

    node->parent = current;
    node->movementCost = movementCost[i];
    if (!presentInClosedList(node))
    {
        // if the probability value of the current node is less then 0.5 (not an obstacle) then add to the open list, else skip it as an obstacle
        // Set astar grid occupancy
        if (grid->getProbabilityValue(node->position) < 0.51)
        {
            node->g = current->g + movementCost[i];
            node->h = (abs(positions[i].getX() - wantedLocation.getX())) + (abs(positions[i].getY() - wantedLocation.getY()));
            node->f = node->g + node->h;

            openList.push_back(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to see if the current node is present in my closedList

bool exists = false;

```
for (int i = 0; i < closedList.size(); i++)
{
    if (closedList[i]->position == currentNode->position)
    {
        closedList[i]->f = currentNode->f;
        closedList[i]->g = currentNode->g;
        closedList[i]->h = currentNode->h;
        closedList[i]->parent = currentNode->parent;

        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

return exists;
```

This returns an `openlist` of possible routes. Next, I select the one with the smallest `F` score, and add this to my `closedList`. I keep doing this routine until the end goal has been found. Finally, once found I go back down the list using the `parent` objects. Here is the rest of the code

```
    // If my parents location is the same as my wanted location, then we've found our position.
    if (locationFound(current, wantedLocation))
    {
        // Now we need to backtrack from our wantedNode looking at the parents of each node to reconstruct the AStar path
        Node* p = current->parent;
        rollingDist = p->g;

        while (!wantedFound)
        {
            if (p->position == startLocation)
            {
                wantedFound = true;
                wantedNodeFound = true;
                break;
            }

            path.push_back(p);
            p = p->parent;

        }

    }
```

Now this is my issue. On every attempt it always finds the wanted location, but never the shortest path. See figure one below.

[image]

*Figure one. Where the yellow marker is the wanted location, and the red darts is the "Path" to my wanted location, and finally, the "Blue" marker is where A star began.*

This is my issue. I can't seem to reconstruct this path.

Comment: Related question with code that can be useful to you: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62233/improving-performance-of-a-search-in-php/62315#62315 If you are interested I can give you the C++ version of this code when I get home.

Comment: Possibly! It would be useful to see how to reconstruct this path. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to update the parent and G if you re-find a node through a shorter path

Comment: I don't think I understand @harold

Comment: Most positions can be reached in more than one way, the *first* time a node is reached is not necessarily the shortest path to it - as long as a node is on the Open list, there are still opportunities to find a shortcut to it. So an important (but somehow often forgotten) part of A* is to check whether a node that you're about to add to the Open list is already in there, if it is *and* the new path to it is better, update the G and parent pointer. Just dumping a new node in it, or checking but not updating, results in nodes reached through detours.

Comment: Ah I do actually do that. So, rather than ignoring it, I modify its G, H and F vals. Though, what do you mean new path? I only ever calculate one path? Do you mean I have to check a new path for every node on the closedList? If so that seems very inefficient.

Comment: Oh good, I don't see where you're doing that though, is the above code simplified? Other than that, manhattan distance is not admissible if diagonal moves have a cost of 1.4 times straight cost, you should be using a proper diagonal distance (see somewhere [here](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html), scroll down a bit). E: it's not that bad, just check whether its already in Open and then maybe change the parent, it is changing the parent that affects the whole path (at worst) but it's a simple operation

Comment: The secret is a priority queue of lowest cost paths. You always operate on the lowest from the priority queue. The other secret, as others mentioned, is that each node may be visited only once. If a node has already been visited, it is accessible via a shorter route, so cull your current route.

Comment: Yeah, so when I was checking to see if the node existed in my closedList, if it was I just ignored it, rather than modifying it! I shall test this to see how it changes the overall working of the system.

Comment: @harold I've updated my post with the checking my closedList.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown not closed, open. Of course, checking whether it's in the closed list is also important (but it does not need to be modified in that case, the point of the closed list is that when a node is in it, it *has* been reached through the shortest path to it).

Comment: Here you go: http://ideone.com/cMuT6i I was told that by definition this is not a A* search algorithm, but whatever. All I know is that it gets the job done and you are guaranteed to find the shortest path. It just doesn't use heuristic that could save search time in exchange of a sub-optimal result, which seems to be the case with your code. Your robot is visiting every node in the general direction of the destination before realizing it simply cannot go straight to it because there's a wall on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap the comments, there are two important problems

- Manhattan distance is not admissible for your movement costs, since the actual shortest path can take a diagonal shortcut that Manhattan distance wouldn't take into account.
- Before adding a new node to the Open list, it not only necessary to check whether it is in the Closed list, but also whether it is already in the Open list. If it is already in the Open list, the G's have to be compared and the smallest must be chosen (together with the corresponding parent pointer).[1]

Since you have octile movement with 10/14 costs, your heuristic function could be (from http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html)

```
function heuristic(node) =
    dx = abs(node.x - goal.x)
    dy = abs(node.y - goal.y)
    return D * (dx + dy) + (D2 - 2 * D) * min(dx, dy)
```

With D = 10, D2 = 14. Of course you can also use anything else admissible but this formula already reflects the actual distance on an open plain so it can't easily be improved.

Finding and updating nodes in the Open list is an annoying part of A* that I'm sure many people would like to pretend isn't necessary, since it means you can't reasonably use any pre-defined priority queue (they lack efficient lookup). It can be done by having a manually implemented binary heap  and a hash table that maps coordinates to their corresponding indexes in the heap. The hash table has to be updated by the heap whenever a node is moved.

[1]: the relevant snippet of pseudo code from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is:

```
    tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
    if neighbor not in openSet  // Discover a new node
        openSet.Add(neighbor)
    else if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
        continue        // This is not a better path.

    // This path is the best until now. Record it!
    cameFrom[neighbor] := current
    gScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore
    fScore[neighbor] := gScore[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. After going through my code and changing it a little, I updated the part that would check if the node is already present in the openList. If it was, and the G-Score is less then it currently is, then a new path has been found, thus the parent and score should be updated. This does create a good enough path for my case. As my assignment is not on Path-Planning, and rather extra work I put in I'm going to leave it where it is - for now!

Thanks everyone