# A star implementation in ROS

Tags: python, ros, a-star

i have been trying to implement A star in python,something similar to [Robotic Path Planning - A* (Star)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310743/robotic-path-planning-a-star/49065780?noredirect=1#comment85136562_49065780).
I wanted to ask how does one get the vector (x,y) coordinates of each grid of cell.I have been trying to do something with occupancy grid data but although it says its 2D,its a 1D dimensional tuple with (-1,0,100) depending on if its empty or not.
     `rospy.wait_for_message('/map',OccupancyGrid)
 rospy.Subscriber('/map',OccupancyGrid,self.update_map)
      def update_map(self,msg3):
        self.data=msg3.data`

The documentation for this msg is https://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html
but i want to get (x,y) coordinates so i can create a node class for each cell something like this:
   `class node():
    def __init__(self):
      int x,
      int y,
      double G
      double F,
      double H,
      node *parent`

How do i get x,y coordinates for each of them so i can create a node out of each cell? P.S. my origin is (-10,-10,0) and i believe it makes a difference in how you calculate.Thanks

Comment: Hi Ayza. Please write your code and approach for your problem, then only people will be able to help you.

Comment: thanks,edited..hope it makes more sense now

Comment: As mentioned in the link you posted, the map `data` is stored in row-major order, starting with (0,0). So the first element `data[0]` corresponds to `(0,0)`, `data[1]` corresponds to `(1,0)` and so on. You can get the height and width (the number of rows and columns) from the map message metadata.

Comment: Thanks!So according to my understanding i can use two loops or something like that to generate x,y for each cell?But one thing that if my map origin is -10,-10 would it mean that my data[0] is (-10,-10) and data[1] is probably (-9,-10) and so on?How to cater for that?